# Loop through URL web based query

Tags: excel, vba

So I have a link like this

```
https://finance.yahoo.com/most-active?offset=0&count=100
```

And I want to use a query like follows

```
let
    Source = Web.Page(Web.Contents("https://finance.yahoo.com/most-active?offset=0&count=100")),
    Data0 = Source{0}[Data],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Data0,{{"Column1", type text}, {"Column2", type text}, {"Column3", type number}, {"Column4", type number}, {"Column5", Percentage.Type}, {"Column6", type text}, {"Column7", type text}, {"Column8", type text}, {"Column9", type text}, {"Column10", type text}})
in
    #"Changed Type"
```

However, I need it to iterate through the url and change the offset=0&count=100. It needs to set offset to 0, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500... 6000.
I am not super used to VBA and run into a lot of syntax errors when I add a for loop.

Comment: `For i = 0 to 6000 step 100` then your code followed by `Next i` should do the trick

Comment: Do you need the 52 week range value?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see you are overlooping. There are 180 results currently i.e. 2 pages. The code below finds the total number of results and only issues the required number of requests. The 52 week range is canvas tag content that is javascript generated and cannot be directly scraped off the page ([Canvas](http://pauljadam.com/demos/canvas.html) content is not part of the DOM except for the fallback content.) If I can work out how to generate the appropriate content I will update this answer.  It is likely that a browser will need to be opened for this and XHR will be dropped as a retrieval method.

I use a basic class to hold the XMLHTTP object so as to avoid the overhead of creating and destroying the object. If in future there are very large numbers of data sets then it is worth adapting this to run batches of requests.

Warning: Hit the site too many times, too quickly and you will likely be throttled (not literally).

**Class module clsHTTP:**

```
Option Explicit

Private http As Object
Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
End Sub

Public Function GetString(ByVal url As String) As String
    Dim sResponse As String
    With http
        .Open "GET", url, False
        .setRequestHeader "If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"
        .send
        sResponse = StrConv(.responseBody, vbUnicode)
        GetString = sResponse
    End With
End Function
```

**Standard module:**

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetTables()
    Dim sResponse As String, html As HTMLDocument, hTable As HTMLTable, http As clsHTTP
    Dim headers(), url As String, offset As Long, ws As Worksheet, results As Long
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    On Error GoTo errhand
    Set http = New clsHTTP: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    headers = Array("Symbol", "Name", "Price (intraday)", "Change", "% Change", "Volume", "Avg Vol(3 month)", "Market Cap", "PE ratio (TTM)", "52 Week Range")

    url = "https://finance.yahoo.com/most-active?offset=0&count=100"
    Set html = New HTMLDocument
    ws.Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, UBound(headers) + 1) = headers

    With html
        .body.innerHTML = http.GetString(url)
        Set hTable = .querySelector("table[class^=W]")
        results = Split(Split(.querySelector("#fin-scr-res-table [class*='Mstart']").innerText, "of ")(1), " results")(0)
        WriteTable hTable, GetLastRow(ws, 1) + 1, ws
    End With

    For offset = 100 To results Step 100
        url = "https://finance.yahoo.com/most-active?offset=" & offset & "&count=100"
        With html
            .body.innerHTML = http.GetString(url)
            Set hTable = .querySelector("table[class^=W]")
            WriteTable hTable, GetLastRow(ws, 1) + 1, ws
        End With
    Next
errhand:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Public Function GetLastRow(ByVal ws As Worksheet, Optional ByVal columnNumber As Long = 1) As Long
    With ws
        GetLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, columnNumber).End(xlUp).Row
    End With
End Function

Public Sub WriteTable(ByVal hTable As HTMLTable, Optional ByVal startRow As Long = 1, Optional ByVal ws As Worksheet)
    If ws Is Nothing Then Set ws = ActiveSheet

    Dim tSection As Object, tRow As Object, tCell As Object, tr As Object, td As Object, r As Long, c As Long, tBody As Object
    r = startRow
    With ws
        Set tBody = hTable.getElementsByTagName("tbody")
        For Each tSection In tBody
            Set tRow = tSection.getElementsByTagName("tr")
            For Each tr In tRow
                Set tCell = tr.getElementsByTagName("td")
                c = 1
                For Each td In tCell
                    .Cells(r, c).Value = td.innerText
                    c = c + 1
                Next td
                r = r + 1
            Next tr
        Next tSection
    End With
End Sub
```

---

As a temporary work around you can use the returned symbols to retrieve the 52 week range info from the quotes landing pages:

```
Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long, symbols(), rowCounter As Long
lastRow = GetLastRow(ws, 1): rowCounter = 2
symbols = ws.Range("A2:A" & lastRow).Value
For i = LBound(symbols, 1) To 3 'UBound(symbols, 1)
    With html
        .body.innerHTML = http.GetString("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/" & symbols(i, 1) & "/key-statistics?p=" & symbols(i, 1))
        ws.Cells(rowCounter, UBound(headers) + 1) = .querySelector("[data-test='FIFTY_TWO_WK_RANGE-value']").innerText
    End With
Next
```

I would strongly advise looking for an API to provide this info.

---

**Avenues to explore with canvas (I will add to this over time):**

1. [Saving HTML5 canvas as image](https://weworkweplay.com/play/saving-html5-canvas-as-image/)
2. [HTML5 Canvas Get Image Data URL](https://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-get-image-data-url/)

Answer (score 0):

Since you've posted an M snippet, I imagine you know where to copy-paste the below to.

Your snippet has been turned into a function called `getYahooData`, which accepts a numeric argument for `offset`, so that we can use it repeatedly.

We basically generate a list of `offsets` (0 to 6000 in steps of 100), then loop over the list whilst calling the `getYahooData` function each time. Each time, the function will return a table of data if it was successful, or `null` if it was not successful.

Once `null` has been returned by the function, it is assumed that no tables exist at the remaining `offsets` (meaning we make no further requests to Yahoo for data).

```
let
    getYahooData = (offset as number) =>
        let
            Source = Web.Page(Web.Contents("https://finance.yahoo.com/most-active?offset=" & Text.From(offset) & "&count=100")),
            dataWasReturned = Table.Contains(Source, [ClassName="W(100%)"]),
            nullOrTable = if not dataWasReturned then null else
                let
                    dataTable = Source{0}[Data],
                    changedTypes = Table.TransformColumnTypes(dataTable, {{"Column1", type text}, {"Column2", type text}, {"Column3", type number}, {"Column4", type number}, {"Column5", Percentage.Type}, {"Column6", type text}, {"Column7", type text}, {"Column8", type text}, {"Column9", type text}, {"Column10", type text}})
                in
                    changedTypes
        in
            nullOrTable,
    offsets = List.Numbers(0, 61, 100),
    // Loop over the list to produce a separate list (which will contain tables or null)
    data = List.Accumulate(offsets, {}, (listOfTables, currentOffset) =>
        let
            runOutOfResults = List.Contains(listOfTables, null),
            toCombine = if runOutOfResults then {null} else {getYahooData(currentOffset)},
            appendToList = List.Combine({listOfTables, toCombine})
        in
            appendToList
        ),
    toTable = Table.FromColumns({offsets, data}, {"Offsets", "Data"}),
    nestedColumnNames =
        let
            excludeNulls = Table.SelectRows(toTable, each not([Data] is null)),
            combineNestedTables = Table.Combine(excludeNulls[Data]),
            columnNames = Table.ColumnNames(combineNestedTables)
        in
            columnNames,
    expandColumn = Table.ExpandTableColumn(toTable, "Data", nestedColumnNames)
in
    expandColumn
```

On my screen, `Column6` to `Column9` have not been transformed into numeric types, as the numbers end with strings `M`, `B`, `T`. You could use `Table.TransformColumns`, `Number.FromText` and/or other M functions to convert them into millions, billions, trillions respectively.